# Splitter Extended Type Multiple Display

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have only 3 ports Display of my Video Card, 2 HDMI and 1 DP, but I need about 4-5 display, I have tried the integrated Graphics were my other display is from my MOBO, won't that cause a problem with my MOBO? will it not overheat or short-circuit? There's also a suggestion from a video that I could do USB to DUAL HDMI. won't that do the same? please advise Thanks.

Comment: It will not overheat or short-circuit.

Comment: It will slow to a crawl, though, & the fans will run at top speed constantly.

Comment: Maybe you can add another GPU?